# hvr-sink css transition on navbar make redirection link not clickable on smartphone only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, transition

all my issue is specified in the title.
I downloaded [a hover css transition package](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/). One of his class is called "hvr-sink".This css transition class on navbar make redirection link not clickable but only on smartphone.
That's work fine for other devices.

EDIT: after having searching a long time I note that only my phone doesn't support the hover. I'm running with an Iphone 4S. 2 friends' mobiles work well.

You can see the [site there](http://remake.medieval-fields.com/content/). Test the navigation bar on computer then on smartphone. The hover sink is implemented on each list element.
I really don't understand why that doesn't work on smartphone only.

My first website works well with "same transition in the navbar".
medieval-fields.com/accueil/

CSS used for the class hvr-sink :

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
     color: #2980b9 !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: exo;
  }

 .navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
    height: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

 .hvr-sink {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sink:hover, .hvr-sink:focus, .hvr-sink:active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(8px);
  transform: translateY(8px);
}
```

navbar link html code for example :

`<li class='hvr-sink'><a href="teamspeak.php">Teamspeak</a></li>`

Edit : I'm using bootstrap

Thanks for reading.
Regards,

Comment: Your navigation seems to work on mobile devices (iPhone4-6 + Android). Might be an issue with your device specifically.

Comment: I decided to remove animation for smaller screen with a media query < 768px. This solve my problem for the moment. But I'm still open for answers :)